# Cannot log WinZip command line process

Tags: logging, command-line, vbscript, zip, winzip

I got the following vbscript test code that zip some test files via WinZip Command Line:

```
Dim strWinZipDir, strZipFileToCreate, strFilesToZip, strWinZip, strCommand

strWinZipDir = "C:\Program Files\WinZip\Winzip32.exe"
strZipFileToCreate = "C:\Users\ext_dirmod_01\Desktop\TestLog.zip"
strFilesToZip = """C:\Users\ext_dirmod_01\Desktop\FacturasGRA.vbs"" ""C:\Users\ext_dirmod_01\Desktop\Test Zip Windows.vbs"""

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strWinZip = objFSO.GetFile(strWinZipDir).ShortPath
strCommand = strWinzip & " -min -a -r """ & strZipFileToCreate & """ " & strFilesToZip

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec(strCommand)

Do While objExec.Status = 0
Loop
```

What I want to do is log the run of the zip process both for successful completion and for error/s appearance. In case of error what I want to do is get the exact message that the WinZip returns.

I have tried several ways:

- Adding a greater than sign (`>`) with a filename at the end of the command line  as it was suggested in [this link](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/166/). This method doesn't write anything on the file.
- Also I tried to get the STDOUT and STDERR of the shell execution but it returns an empty string.

Does anyone know what else I can/should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CheranShunmugavel pointed out in a comment to another answer the knowledge base article refers to the [WinZip Command Line utility](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.html). If you want to work with WinZip on the command line I strongly recommend you get that add-on, even though the regular WinZip executable does support [some basic command line parameters](http://www.memecode.com/docs/winzip.html).

Note that if you want to use output redirection (`>`) you *must* run the command in CMD, because redirection is provided by the command interpreter. For simplified handling I would also recommend using the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method rather than the [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method unless you need to programatically read from STDOUT and/or STDERR.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
rc = objShell.Run("cmd /c " & strCommand & " >C:\path\to\your.log 2>&1", 0, True)

If rc <> 0 Then WScript.Echo "An error occurred (" & rc & ")."
WScript.Quit rc
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a graphical program. It doesn't use a console. Therefore you can't.

If you used genuine programs you'll find PKZip has command line versions. https://www.pkware.com/software/pkzip

Comment: Also, the KB article linked to in the question is about the "WinZip Command Line Support Add-on". I don't know if that's a separate download or an option when installing, but that's another option to look at.

Comment: Winzip started a graphical program that called pkzip's Dos programs in Win 3.1. PkZip has a ZIP REPAIR UTILITY which is why I link to them.